# Weird problem in running bash script

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal

I wrote a bash script that fetches lyrics from a website. The script is here --> http://scrippets.wordpress.com/2011/02/01/fetching-lyrics-of-songs-from-the-terminal/  (the indentations in the script are correct unlike how it looks on the blog)
This script works perfectly well when executed from the terminal. Now i created a custom keyboard shortcut using compiz commands, that executes the following command when the right key combination is pressed :

```
gnome-terminal --working-directory="/home/tapan/sandbox/bash/" --window-with-profile=lyrics -e "/home/tapan/sandbox/bash/lyrics.sh" -t "`rhythmbox-client --print-playing`"
```

I created a new profile called "lyrics" to give the terminal that opens up a custom look. When i open up a terminal with this profile and run the script, it works perfectly fine again. However, when i use the keyboard shortcut to run the custom command, i get the following error:

```
Pink Floyd - Is There Anybody Out There?
wget: missing URL
Usage: wget [OPTION]... [URL]...

Try `wget --help' for more options.
cat: 3.txt: No such file or directory
```

I cannot figure out whats wrong. I mean if it works perfectly well in the terminal normally, why shouldn't this work? Any suggestions?
PS: The script i have written is pretty elementary and noobish, so any suggestions to improve it are also welcome in the comments :)

EDIT: The output has changed a little, now it just shows the name of the song playing and nothing else. Though sometimes it still shows the wget error.

EDIT2: When i run that gnome terminal command from a terminal, it works. The problem is only when running it with the keyboard shortcut using compiz commands or if i use the run dialog (the alt+f2 one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two wget commands should probably have the url variables in double quotes, for example: `wget -q -U Mozilla -O 1.txt $link` should be `wget -q -U Mozilla -O 1.txt "$link"`

Comment: The output changed a little. I've edited the original question.

Comment: i'd guess this means you are getting past the first wget, but 2.txt is empty

Comment: What i dont understand is why doesnt it work with that command when it works perfectly when executed in a regular terminal!

Comment: can you echo $searchq in that script so that you see that the substitutions are doing what you expect

Comment: @stew : Done. Works as expected. Check out EDIT2. Looks like some compiz commands thing rather than something with the script.

Answer (score 0):

You need to uriencode your song title so that special characters like '?', '&', '%', and '+' are not passed literally in your URL.

```
name3=${name2//\?/%3F}
searchq=${name3// /+}
```

will handle the `?`'s. I don't know of a more general solution in `bash` without resorting to one-line Perl or Python scripts.

Comment: yeah, i am thinking of adding something like that. But bash is not really that good when it comes to string manipulation (or i am not that good at bash). The main problem are the brackets because a lot of songs tend to have "[live], (demo)" in which case i would just like to remove everything inside and including the brackets. But again this is OT since it affects only like 5% of my music library and i'm ok with that at this point. The main thing is to have a keyboard shortcut to display the lyrics in a terminal.

Comment: Tada! Urlencode/decode in bash: https://github.com/Daenyth/dotfiles/blob/master/.bashrc#L194

Comment: Wow, thanks so much for that Daenyth! I'll try and incorporate it. @mob - read EDIT 2, maybe it helps you figure something out. Sure doesn't help me :(.

Comment: @Daenyth - btw i love your bashrc. I am going to shamelessly steal a lot of that :D (I will credit you in the comments ofc :) )

Comment: @tapan: I got most of mine the same way, so don't feel bad ;). The git commit introducing those functions has the blog post that I cribbed them from, can't remember where.